# Verificar extensão de um arquivo

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando verificar a extensão de um arquivo enviado pelo usuário salvo em uma variável `receita`, porém ele sempre vai me trazer o erro, pois ele está lendo `"receita"` e não o que está dentro da variável `receita`.

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
function run(receita){

    var extensoes, ext, valido;
    extensoes = new Array('.txt','.pdf','.doc','.png','.jpeg','.jpg');

    ext = receita.substring(receita.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
    valido = false;

    for(var i = 0; i <= receita.length; i++){
        if(extensoes[i] == ext){
            valido = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(valido){
        return "Enviado com sucesso";
    }

    return "Extenção incorreta";
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou normalmente

Comment: Aqui, independentemente do arquivo que eu anexar ele sempre da como "Extensão incorreta"

Comment: Acredito que o problema esta na hora de usar a função e não na função, vou colocar dois exemplo para você ver o que estou falando

Comment: Incua o HTML de como vc está chamando a função.

Comment: Veja, esta funcionando normalmente https://jsfiddle.net/gnw31o20/

Comment: Você colocou para retornar "Extenção incorreta" sem o `else`.

Comment: O certo não seria  `if(valido){ return "Enviado com sucesso"; } else { return "Extenção incorreta"; }`

Comment: @LaércioLopes Não precisa do `else` por causa do `return` que já sai da função.

Comment: @Sam isso mesmo, eu tinha testado com console.log.

Comment: Esse `for` também está errado e só daria certo por coincidência. Veja, se vc adicionar mais uma extensão na array e chamar `d.jpg` irá retornar `"Extenção incorreta"` porque vc está se baseando no tamanho da string e não no tamanho da array.

Comment: Em vez de `i <= receita.length` teria que ser `i <= extensoes.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje existe uma alternativa mais atual e funcional para descobrir se determinado valor pertence a uma array. Pode-se utilizar o método `Array.prototype.includes()` do `ES7`.

```js
function run() {

    var receita = document.getElementById("receita").value;
    var ext, valido;
    
    ext = receita.substring(receita.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();

    valido = ['.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg'].includes(ext);

    if (valido) {
        alert("Extensão válida!");
    } else {
        alert("Extensão incorreta.");
    }                

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="receita" id="receita" size=50 placeholder="Nome do arquivo">
        <button onclick="run();">Enviar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Porém** o método, `includes()` não é suportado em navegadores mais antigos, isso pode ser um problema se você não utiliza de algum transpilador para fazer a conversão de ES7 para ES5.

Compatibilidade ([can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=indexof)) `Array.prototype.indexOf`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Compatibilidade ([can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=includes)) `Array.prototype.includes`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referência:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Answer (score -2):

```js
function run() {

    var receita = document.getElementById("receita").value;
    var extensoes, ext, valido;
    extensoes = new Array('.txt', '.pdf', '.doc', '.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg');
    ext = receita.substring(receita.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
    valido = false;

    for (var i = 0; i <= receita.length; i++) {
        if (extensoes[i] === ext) {
            valido = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valido) {
        alert("Extensão válida!");
    } else {
        alert("Extensão incorreta.");
    }                

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="receita" id="receita" size=50 placeholder="Nome do arquivo">
        <button onclick="run();">Enviar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seu código está incorreto. Coloque `d.jpg` no nome do arquivo e verá.

Comment: Continua o mesmo problema. O problema é no `else`, porque irá entrar nele na primeira extensão que não bater com o item da array.

Comment: Alterei aqui já.